# I do not see a Speech Input Source script in my mrtk (mixed reality toolkit) in the project search bar in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to implement **voice commands** into my unity project to eventually be used in the HoloLens. At the moment, I am simply trying to make a cube change colors using the speech input handler script and **speech input source script.** I have the handler script but I **can't find the source script** anywhere. How do I obtain the source script? Why do I not have it? I am using Unity 2018.4.12f1 and I am using the Mixed Reality Toolkit. If you need additional info to help me please ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions after MRTK2, SpeechInputSource is no longer needed. Instead, keyword service (e.g., Windows Speech Input Manager) must be added to the input system's data providers. Please check out the SpeechInputExample scene to understand how to use speech input.

The guide you are reading may be outdated, please read the [official documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Speech.html) to learn how to use Speech function in the latest version of MRTK.